# How to select max length column data in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, group-by, max, string-length

I have data as below:

```
No,Code,Name
1,code1,code1 name
2,code2,This name for code2
3,code3,code3 name
```

I want to select the record 2, and I tried SQL as below, but I got error `ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here`, what can I do?

```
select code, name from my_mst where max(length(name)) group by name;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a subquery to identify the max length:

```
SELECT code, name
FROM my_mst
WHERE LENGTH(name) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(name)) FROM my_mst)
```

This would work well with the particular sample data set you showed us.  However, it has a limitation, namely that it would return multiple records if there were a tie for the max name length.  If you wanted to break that tie using, e.g., the code, then you could consider using analytic functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT code, name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(name) DESC, code) rn
    FROM my_mst
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: former is ok, but I am not sure what does mean about tie, later has error as below 'ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected'.

Comment: @mikezang Reload your page, as @Oto pointed out, I neglected to add a `FROM` clause to my query.

Comment: so this will be the same as your later one, sure? `select * from (SELECT code, name, length(name) FROM my_mst WHERE LENGTH(name) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(name)) FROM my_mst) order by code) where rownum = 1;`

Comment: I don't understand where your `rownum` is coming from.  For your particular example, both queries would give the same result.  In the case of a tie for length, the first query would give _all_ ties, while the second one would return the record with the smallest `code`.